# Extjs combobox mapping a table with thousands of records

Tags: extjs

my table has a foreign key field that points to a table with very much records.

How is the best practice to show this field in the form ?

Using ComboBox is very nice for small tables, but with hugh tables it's not a good choice.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created our own component(picker) for this. It extends combobox and it's store has only one record. When user clicks on picker, popup window with grid should open, when user selects record in grid, this record(id and displayName) goes to picker.
It looks like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

Better go for Grid with paging if you have multiple columns to be displayed.
Else you can go for Combobox with paging too.